# Setting up tmk_keyboard firmware on Arduino Nano

Tags: c, arduino, keyboard, usb, firmware

I'm trying to install keyboard firmware to my Arduino Nano chip. There's `tmk_keyboard` code project for that, in this example I install **one_key.vusb** but I tried other setups as well.

```
git clone https://github.com/tmk/tmk_keyboard.git
cd tmk_keyboard/keyboard/onekey
make clean
make -f Makefile.vusb
sudo avrdude -C <arduino dir>/etc/avrdude.conf  -p atmega328p -vv -c arduino  -b 57600 -P /dev/ttyUSB0 -D -Uflash:w:onekey_vusb.hex:i
```

Then after replugging tried shorting `pb0` and `pb1` as pointed out in [one_key docs](https://github.com/tmk/tmk_keyboard/blob/master/keyboard/onekey/README.md) (which are `d9` and `d8` on Arduino), but no effect.

I also tried setting `MCU = atmega328p` and `F_CPU = 16000000L`in the **Makefile.vusb**, and building again, but still no effect

Comment: There is also F_CPU = 12000000UL and Arduino Nano runs at 16MHz. The 12MHz crystal might be even essential for USB as it's clock speeds in different modes are multiples of 12MHz.

Comment: @KIIV see my update. It did not work :(